# Dropdown with no text

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want to achieve this effect:
[image]

I want to have a dropdown arrow pointing downwards and empty space before it. I also want to have the options appearing exactly below as shown here.

So far I have tried this:

```
<div>
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-right" text="&#160;&nbsp;" class="m-2">
    <b-dropdown-item>Phone Number</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Email</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>DeviceToken</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

I have tried to fill it with empty spaces and the ASCI codes are   or  . Neither of those work.
This is visualized as this:
[image]

Please help I have spent couple of hours on this and I am stuck. I have also tried different bootstrap elements to no luck.

Comment: Try this `style="color: transparent;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside text you can't add ASCI Code. You can do like,

```
<div id="app">
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-right" class="m-2 col-5">
    <b-dropdown-item>Phone Number</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Email</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>DeviceToken</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

[image]

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-architecture-5enb3)